# Gremlins are investing in stock

Tags: finance

Gremlin Industries will pay a dividend of \$1.80 per share this year. It is expected that this dividend will grow by 4% each year in the future. The current price of gremlins stock is \$22.40 per share. What is Gremlin's equity cost of capital?

The answer is 12% percent but I cannot figure out why. The problem is missing certain pieces of information that I need for each formula I use.

Comment: It accidently got edited weird, sorry. It supposed to state that the stock will grow by 4% each year. Also, that the current price is 22.40 per share

Comment: On this site, \$...\$ is used to enter nicely typeset mathematics, not to represent the dollar sign symbol.  To represent dollar signs, type `\$`.

Comment: This question is about finance and finance-specific formulae, not mathematics, so this is not quite the right place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $i$ is Gremlin's equity cost of capital. Then, based on the [Dividend Discount Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_discount_model), the price of the stock can be constructed as follows:
$$22.40 = 1.80(1+i)^{-1}+1.80(1.04)(1+i)^{-2}+...$$

This is an infinite geometric series with first term $1.80(1+i)^{-1}$ and common ratio $(1.04)(1+i)^{-1}$ and can be represented by: $$22.40 = 1.80(1+i)^{-1}\frac{1}{1-(1.04)(1+i)^{-1}}$$ or $$22.40=1.80\frac{1}{1+i-1.04}$$

Solving, $i=0.12$ (rounded)